# Adiabatic QC: are there known difficult problems with spectral gap not exponentially decreasing?

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-computer, algorithms

[Adiabatic quantum computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_quantum_computation) require slow evolution to maintain global minimum: $O(1/g^2)$ time, where $g$ is spectral gap: distance between two lowest energies.

The danger is that this spectral gap might decrease exponentially with problem size - this way evolution would need exponentially long time, and additionally temperature would need to decrease exponentially to distinguish the global optimum.

To see that this danger is a real, let us look at [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (NP-complete): for $k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ large natural numbers, decide if $X=\{\sum a_i k_i: a\in\{-1,1\}^n \}$ contains zero? As $X$ is kind of sum of binary random variables, its density usually asymptotically resembles Gaussian distribution. While $n$ grows, width of this distribution grows linearly with $n$, while the number of points is $2^n$, hence distance between 0 and first nonzero value ("spectral gap") should drop exponentially.

This issue seems universal while converting difficult computational problem into global optimization problem - the number of local optima grows exponentially, on range of energies growing much slower.

Hence I wanted to ask if there are known difficult computational problems for which we know that spectral gap does not decrease exponentially - for which adiabatic QC makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Adiabatic quantum computing is [equivalent](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405098) to standard digital (i.e., gate based) quantum computing. Thus any problem that can be solved efficiently (in polynomial time) using digital quantum computation can also be solved efficiently using adiabatic quantum computing.

Basically, you can map any gate-based computation to a Hamiltonian whose groundstate encodes the final state of the computation. To do the adiabatic computation, you introduce a `driver' Hamiltonian and interpolate slowly between the two Hamiltonians. The minimum inverse gap ($1/g$) of the interpolated Hamiltonian scales polynomially with the number of gates in the computation. So, in principle, you could factor numbers using this trick: just map Shor's algorithm to an equivalent Hamiltonian and prepare its groundstate.

I admit this is a bit of a cop-out answer. I don't know of any `native' applications of AQC that show an exponential speedup, but they probably exist.

Comment: Thank you, the most important is this "The minimum inverse gap (1/g) of the interpolated Hamiltonian scales polynomially with the number of gates in the computation", saying that Shor/factorization is example for my question. Could you suggest a paper explaining it in accessible form?